# Python OpenCv get text on very noise area

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I need to detect a text on a very noise area like the following:
[image]

Is there a way to eliminate this contrast ?
I tried using an adaptative binary threshold, or reverse threshold but there was still much noise

```
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, thresholdBLockSize, thresholdSubtractContant)
```

The result of the binary or binary inverse is as following:
[image]

Then I thought on canny edge detecting and dilating the image using CV_CROSS so it would expand on all sides, the pattern as expected gets merged on the text as a blob

```
  kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(5,5))
  morph = cv2.dilate(edged,kernel,iterations = 1)
```

[image]

My best idea so far would be to try to find closed contours and do a filtering by size.
I was wondering if there was a better line of thought on cases like this one.

Maybe something on color filtering could work but I also have black and white images so that would be a partial solution

Comment: It would help if you'd use a sharp image with decent resolution.
Do you need to "detect" this text as mentioned or do you need to read it as well?
why do you need to read this text at all? I assume it's a bank note. Their content is known. what is the purpose of this?

Comment: It's a driver's license. The top part is fixed, the bottom part is not. I just discovered today that it color varies as well. Going from white to the same green as the top one.  I needed to detect it as text (Working on that, trying to see if I can make an SFT implementation) and try to pass it to the OCR. But for the moment I think it would be too much work for too little value. Still is a cool problem to solve